# Google+ and googleCalendar API : Error "Cannot redeclare class Google_Acl"

Tags: php, class, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am using the google api php client.

Howewer, when I'm trying to include the three following libraries:

```
require_once app_path().'/library/googleapi/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';
require_once app_path().'/library/googleapi/contrib/Google_TasksService.php';
require_once app_path().'/library/googleapi/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
```

I get : `Cannot redeclare class Google_Acl` on line 784 of `Google_CalendarService.php`.
I know I could modify `Google_CalendarService.php` so that the class is only created if it doesn't exist, but this is kind of messy.

I need to load both libraries at the same time to create a valid AuthURL to authorize requests on google plus (to get the profile image) and the calendar (to get the calendar).

What's the best workaround for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it is not possible to use these 3 libraries together

**Reply from google code.google-api-php-client**

> Unfortunately its not the same object - there is name collision in
>   this version of the library. The alpha version 1.0.0 includes better
>   name generation that avoids this:
>   http://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/
>
> The workaround at the moment is not to include both at the same time
>   unfortunately.
>
> https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/issues/detail?id=439